# Upgrading Next.js Project to v13: Chakra UI Color Mode Issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I'm currently in the process of upgrading my Next.js project from version 12 to version 13, which has required changing the 'src' dictionary to 'app'.

I've come across an issue where my Chakra UI code, which previously worked in v12, is no longer functioning properly.

Specifically, when I toggle color mode, only the components using 'useColorModeValue' are displaying the correct colors, while the background and text colors remain unchanged.

I'm unsure why this is happening and would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to fix it.

styles

```
const styles: Styles = {
  global: (props: GlobalStyleProps) => ({
    body: {
      color:
        props.colorMode === "light" ? light.onBackground : dark.onBackground,
      bg: props.colorMode === "light" ? light.background : dark.background,
      maxW: "100vw",
      overflowX: "hidden",
    },
    "*::placeholder": { opacity: 0.6 },
    "*, *::before, &::after": {
      outlineColor: props.colorMode === "light" ? light.outline : dark.outline,
      padding: 0,
      margin: 0,
      boxSizing: "border-box",
      //outline: "1px solid green", 
    },
    a: {
      color: "inherit",
      textDecoration: "none",
    },
  }),
};
```

theme.ts

```
const theme = extendTheme({
  config,
  colors: {
    light,
    dark,
    elevation,
  },
  fonts: {
    heading: `'Roboto', sans-serif`,
    body: `'Open Sans', sans-serif`,
  },
  styles,
});
```

next js 13 layout.tsx

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body>
            <CacheProvider>
              <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
                <ColorModeScript
                  initialColorMode={theme.config?.initialColorMode}
                />
                <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
                  <Layout>
                    <>{/* <Navbar /> */}</>
                    <>
                      <Header />
                    </>
                    <>{children}</>
                  </Layout>
                </AnimatePresence>
              </ChakraProvider>
            </CacheProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: Any error in any console? Browser or server?

Comment: I didn't see any errors in the console. To solve this problem, I built a top-level component and used useColorModeValue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make sure that you've updated to the latest Chakra UI version? The latest versions (especially 2.5.0) seem to have numerous changes regarding NextJS. I had the same issue before updating to a more recent version. Also make sure to check the [Getting Started Guide](https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/nextjs-guide), as there is a special section for setting it up with the `app` directory. Hope this helps.

Edit: especially make sure to use the `@chakra-ui/next-js` package and wrap your entire application (in `layout.tsx|js`) with the `<CacheProvider>` that this package provides. Also, I can confirm that color modes are indeed not working for me as well in my theme configuration. I would suggest filing an official bug report via the GitHub repo.